# Slider Range with dynamic colors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is the look I'm going for, the functionality would be that you can set a range for each risk level, but they are dependent on each other, so they would ideally build on each other.

So in the first line the default value is 0.00 - 1.66 and I need the range slider from 0.00 to the 1.66 to be green.

In the MODERATE line the default values are 1.67 - 2.33.

What I am trying to represent in HIGH row is that this is a cumilative setting and that each new row is built upon by the last.

I am running into a ton of issues with styling and functionality.

This might be a huge ask and I'm not skilled in sliders. I've been trying to get the front end design working enough for the dev team to understand the build that is coming down the pipe.

```
 function refreshValues() {
 var lowSlider = 
 $("#lowSlider").slider("value");   }
       $(function () {
       $("#lowSlider").slider({
        orientation: "horizontal",
        range: "min",
        value: 1.66,
        min: 0.00,
        max: 5,
        step: 0.01,
        slide: refreshValues,
        slide: function (event, ui) {

 $("#low1").val("0.00" + " - " + ui.value);},
         change: refreshValues
            });
 $("#low1").val("0.00" + " - " + $("#lowSlider").slider("value"));
            });
                         <input type="text" id="low1" class="risk-value > 
      text-primary" readonly>                 
    <div id="lowSlider" class="addSlide"></div>




 function refreshValues() {

 var modSlider =
  $("#modSlider").slider("value"); }

 $(function () {
 $("#modSlider").slider({
    orientation: "horizontal",
    range: "min",
    value: 2.33,
    min: 1.67,
    max: 5.00,
    step: 0.01,
    slide: refreshValues,
    slide: function (event, >ui) { $("#mod1").val("1.67" + " - " +  
    ui.value);
        },
   change: refreshValues});
     $("#mod1").val("1.67" + " - >      " + ("#modSlider").slider("value"));
           });

   <input type="text" id="mod1" > 
   class="risk-value text-warning" readonly>
 <div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-primary" role="progressbar">  </div>
  <div id="modSlider" class="addSlide"></div>
```

Comment: Pls remove all `>` in the code section

Comment: It is unclear exactly what you are asking. Could you rephrase the question and what you are trying to do?

Comment: Couldn't get you clearly. Do you want to set colors in each slider ?

Comment: sorry, this is my first question here and i don't quite understand the formatting tools in the editor.

Comment: it would be low slider, low color + moderate slider, low color + moderate color + high slider